# Install printer driver 32 bit

Tags: printer

because most of the available printer drivers do not support 64 bit, I'd like to know, how I can install my brother driver in Loki. Many thanks.

Regards, Dragomrak

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base:i386 libgcc1:i386 libc6:i386
```

The follow [these](https://web.archive.org/web/20140319074536/http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html) instructions for your Brother printer.

Or in Synaptic, search and install these:

```
brother-lpr-drivers-laser
brother-cups-wrapper-laser
brother-lpr-drivers-common
```